# Msyql. Recuperar información de dos tablas relacionadas a traves de un campo

Tags: mysql

Tengo que realizar una consulta a base de datos y no veo como hacerlo en una sola llamada (no sé si se puede).
Tengo 2 tablas, una de tareas, y otra de personas_asiganadas a las tareas. Se relacionan por el idTarea.

```
    TAREAS
    ------------
    idTarea
    idCreador
    asunto
    fecha
    descripcion
    ------------
    
    TAREAS_ASIGNADAS
    ------------
    id
    idTarea
    usuario
    ------------
```

Se puede asignar la misma tarea a varias personas, por lo que en la tabla de tareas_asignadas pueden existir varios registros con el mismo idTarea.

¿Existe alguna manera de que con una única sentencia sql recuperar la información de la tarea y todos los usuarios asignados?

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Agrega la tabla de personas_asignadas con sus campos

Comment: Para unir en una consulta a dos o mas tablas se utiliza el INNER JOIN,  te pongo la manera genérica de como se utiliza:  SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;

Comment: El INNER JOIN está bien cuando únicamente se relaciona un registro de una tabla con un registro de la otra tabla, pero cuando la relación es de 1 registro a varios registros la información que devuelve es repetida en muchos casos

Comment: la tabla de personas_asignadas es  
    TAREAS_ASIGNADAS
    ------------
    id  ;  
    idTarea  ;
    usuario  ;
    ------------          

y se relaciones entre ellas a través del idTarea. POr tanto puede exitir un tarea que tenga vairo usuarios asignados. Es decir 1 tarea en la tabla TAREAS y varios usuarios asignados en la tabla TAREAS_ASIGNADAS con el mimsmo idTarea

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta para responder a comentarios pidiendo info adicional. Añade la información faltante, junto con tu código y errores. Aquí abajo en los comentarios el código es ilegible. In-ten-ta-lo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si amigo, existe la forma, para esto debes crear una llave foranea en el campo idTarea de la tabla TAREAS_ASIGNADAS que apunte a la tabla TAREAS. Esto lo harias asi:

```
ALTER TABLE TAREAS_ASIGNADAS ADD FOREIGN KEY (idTarea) REFERENCES TAREAS(idTarea) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

ON DELETE CASCADE: Esto hara que si borras un registro padre se borre el registro hijo

ON UPDATE CASCADE: Esto hara que si actualizas un registro padre se actualize el registro hijo

Pero a mi vista, tienes mal la relacion. Las tablas deberian relacionarse por id de usuario y no por id de tarea. Yo crearia una tabla intermedia entre TAREAS y TAREAS_ASIGNADAS, llamada USUARIOS. Esto para que tu tabla TAREAS ASIGNADAS tenga 2 llaves foraneas una apuntando a USUARIOS y otra apuntando a TAREAS.

Para hacer la consulta a varias tablas usarias INNER JOIN de la forma:

SELECT tar.nombre_tarea,us.nombre_usuario,etc..  FROM TAREAS_ASIGNADAS tag INNER JOIN TAREAS tar ON tag.idTarea = tar.id INNER JOIN USUARIOS us ON tag.idUsuario = us.id;

Puede ser mucha informacion, pero con que estudies Llaves foraneas y relaciones entre tablas deberias poder hacer lo que quieres.